# Local variable (int) might not be initialized before accessing

Tags: c#, value-type

I have the following method defined in a class:

```
public bool LogOff(string sessionId)
{
   int res;
   // Some non related code here..
   if (res == 1)
   {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

What's strange to me is that I'm getting a "Local variable might not be initialized before accessing" error from Visual Studio (I do have ReSharper installed) on the IF clause. Why is this the case when "res" is a value type and as such should default to 0? I should point out that if I specifically set the value of res to 0 then it's all OK.

What am I missing here? I thought these are the basics of programming but apparently I'm not familiar with the basics...

Comment: the error tells you what you need to do you need to do `int res = 0` initialize it to a value

Comment: @nvoigt It's not a duplicate because that example is dealing with reference type DateTime while this question is about value types but ok...

Comment: @Marko Both value and reference types have a default value. Both emit this error when they are not explicitly set. For this post, there is no difference between value and reference type. The accepted answer does not mention any difference in this case, either. Therefore, to me it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to "why does C# work this way" is invariably "because that's what's in the spec." Section 5.3.2 of the C# language specification lists the variables that are not initially assigned:

> - Instance variables of initially unassigned struct variables.
> - Output parameters, including the this variable of struct instance constructors.
> - **Local variables, except those declared in a catch clause or a foreach statement.**

As to why this is an error, Section 5.3 states

> A variable must be definitely assigned at each location where its value is obtained.

If you initialize the value as `int res = new int();`, you will get the default value of zero. The more common way is mentioned in other answers, which is to set it to zero explicitly. Relying on default values just makes code less readable with no real advantages.

Comment: @Marko Glad to help. The language specification is often overlooked as a resource, but it's actually quite readable and useful when you get into these types of questions. You can even buy an annotated copy for further clarification.

Answer (score 9):

> Why is this the case when "res" is a value type and as such should default to 0?

Even though the value defaults to 0 in member fields, locals require explicitly setting the value. The compiler will warns you that you are using it without initializing it since that's likely a bug.

While this "technically" could be fine with a zero initialized default from a logical standpoint, from a real-world standpoint, the fact that you haven't ever set the value before checking it is either 1) useless (the `if` would never be true) or 2) a bug (you meant to set the value, but something changed).

In either case, a warning is there to help you prevent either scenario from occurring accidentally.

> I should point out that if I specifically set the value of res to 0 then it's all OK.

When you do this, you're specifically providing a value, so the compiler no longer warns you.

Comment: It's not a warning I am unable to build the solution. I get this error: Use of unassigned local variable 'res'... This is what's confusing me...

Comment: @Marko Locals != fields - you MUST initialize a local variable before using them.  The compiler treats this as an error instead of "just handling it" because it's a common source of real bugs.

Comment: @Marko I think the confusion stems because the behavior is different for members of types.  Within a type (ie: a field), a value type gets zero-initialized.  Local members within a method do not necessarily have that behavior - the language requires you to assign them some value.

Answer (score 2):

C# requires all variables to be initialized prior to use.  For local variables like this you need to initialize them explicitly.  Fields in a struct or class don't need to be initialized explicitly because they receive their default value as part of object construction.

So here, you just need to do

```
int res = 0;
```

and all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the uninitialized value is not guaranteed to be 0 by the C#.  Per the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029), uninitialized variables may not be used because C# is designed to prevent you from doing obviously bad things.

The primary reason that some other languages (notably, C and C++) *do* allow this is because it is extra work on the compiler writer to detect and flag this condition.

EDIT: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is the relevant part of the C# language spec:

Comment: What do you mean it's not guaranteed? How can in not be if it's a value type? What is the value of a declared int when I don't specify the default value myself???

Comment: It depends on how the CLR is implemented.  If it does not explicitly zero out that memory, then the value will be whatever was last stored at the physical location in memory that holds your variable.

Comment: So there is some sort of a value in there? Could that value be null? I still don't understand why not allow me to build if the value will be something even if it's 12345...

Comment: It has a value, you're just not allowed to use it.  Them's the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Default initialization applies to class/struct members, which doesn't apply here because res is a local variable; as a variable, and not a data member, the "initialization required before use" applies.